# How to invoke an action of its own service as soon as the service is up in moleculer js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, service, action, moleculer

I am working in moleculer js, in which there is a requirement to call action/handler function of its own service to prepopulate the values from the DB and ecternal API call. If I do using started() method, service throwing below error.

**[Runner] Service 'serviceName.actionName' is not found. ServiceNotFoundError: Service 'serviceName.actionName' is not found.**

Could you share the beginner documentation/resources for reference? TIA

Answer (score 2):

The service can call its own actions via `this.actions.myAction(params, opts)`. It's available before the service started/registered.